# How to get execution time of an AppleScript?

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, bash

I have seen some more advanced AppleScript users mention efficiency of their AppleScripts in terms of execution time.

Is there an AppleScript method for getting the execution time?

I know there is `time` when calling `do shell script`. I have this working in a loop:

```
set googURL to (do shell script "{ time googler --np -n 1 -w imdb.com " & movie_title & " " & movie_year & " | grep https | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' ; } 2>> ~/Desktop/time.txt")
```

(on a side note I couldn't figure out how to get the output of the `time` command to output to Replies, it was being interpreted as part of the `grep` command)

I want to get the time it takes to execute the entire AppleScript.

Comment: More advanced scripters tend to use Script Debugger, which has a built-in timer.

Comment: RE: "(on a side note I couldn't figure out how to get the output of the `time` command to output to Replies, it was being interpreted as part of the `grep` command)" --  I don't think `grep` has anything to do with it as just a simple `do shell script "time sleep 1"` doesn't return anything either. My guess would be that it does work in _non-interactive shells_, which is what a `do shell script` _command_ uses.

Comment: @red_menace as usual a person has to know half an answer in order to Google it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The sad part is that even the free version of Script Debugger stomps Apple's Script Editor pretty hard.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one AppleScript solution that you may be interested in.

```
set startTime to current date

-- Your Code Here

set timeTaken to ((current date) - startTime as string) & " Seconds"

activate
display alert "Script Timer" message "Running This Code Took " & ¬
    timeTaken buttons {"OK"} giving up after 5
```

*This is just a general solution which will return the value in seconds (whole).  This will not return fractions of seconds.*